# Auto-updating GPS location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was using Unity's GPS System and noticed that it never updated. I had to close the app and launch it again in order to get my current position.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject longText;
    public GameObject latText;

    IEnumerator Start() {
        Text longitudeText = longText.GetComponent<Text>();
        Text latitudeText = latText.GetComponent<Text>();

        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            yield break;

        Input.location.Start();

        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        if (maxWait < 1) {
            print("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }


        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed) {
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        } else {
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
            longitudeText.text = "Longitude: " + Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            latitudeText.text = "Latitude: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude;
        }

        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate some help in making this auto-update to my current location! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you expect it to update? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have will show the GPS location once then  `Input.location.Stop();` is called to stop the GPS.

Put

```
print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
longitudeText.text = "Longitude: " + Input.location.lastData.longitude;
latitudeText.text = "Latitude: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude;
```

in a `while` loop then add `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);` inside the `while` loop to wait for some time. Another way to do this is to start another coroutine that will update the GPS location over time.

Something like this:

```
public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject longText;
    public GameObject latText;

    IEnumerator coroutine;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        coroutine = updateGPS();

        Text longitudeText = longText.GetComponent<Text>();
        Text latitudeText = latText.GetComponent<Text>();

        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            yield break;

        Input.location.Start();

        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            print("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }


        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
            longitudeText.text = "Longitude: " + Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            latitudeText.text = "Latitude: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude;
            StartCoroutine(coroutine);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator updateGPS()
    {
        float UPDATE_TIME = 3f; //Every  3 seconds
        WaitForSeconds updateTime = new WaitForSeconds(UPDATE_TIME);

        while (true)
        {
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
            //longitudeText.text = "Longitude: " + Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            //latitudeText.text = "Latitude: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude;
            yield return updateTime;
        }
    }

    void stopGPS()
    {
        Input.location.Stop();
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        stopGPS();
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the app crashed after first opening it, then I had to reopen it, at which point it crashed after about 20 seconds. Every time I open it after that, it also crashes after 20 seconds, until I fully quit it, then it crashes immediately. It does show my location data, though. I'm on Android Lollipop by the way.

Comment: I don't see anything that could crash there app here.What is your Unity version? Could you try try this on another Android device and see if the crash still persist?

Comment: I am using Unity 5.5.0f3, I tried it on another Android device and the same thing happened.

Comment: Is this the only script in your project? If not, can you disable other scripts and see if it is still crashing. If it yes, please close Unity, zip the project and upload it somewhere. Provide the link here and I will take a look at it.

Comment: Here is the link to the project: http://www.mediafire.com/file/jkmxznc1j9j9fc6/GPS.zip

Comment: Check back in few hours. I am busy right now but will tell you if I find anything

Comment: Hi, the crash problem you have is a bug in 5.5.3 that is not yet fixed. You can use unity 5.4 until this bug is fixed. These are the references https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/input-location-start-causes-android-build-to-crash-directly-after-startup.443920/ and https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-location-app-crashes-due-to-error-jstring-has-wrong-type-android-dot-location-dot-location. You can also use a [paid](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/67473) until this bug is fixed. I wouldn't. I would just use Unity 5.4 until it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the information, and the code to fix the original problem!